# Using RealmSwift to create a pin code, trying to call RealmSwift function

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I am using RealmSwift to create a pin code object for an iOS app I am building.
I have created a constructor and a few basic functions to check the pin, enter new pin, etc.
I can set a new pin using the pin object created in RealmSwift, but I am having problems checking it.
Here is the RealmSwift part:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class pinCode: Object   {
@objc dynamic var pin = ""
}

protocol pinCodeManager {
func checkForExistingPin() -> Bool
func enterNewPin(newPin:String)
func checkPin(pin:String) -> Bool
}

class manager:pinCodeManager    {
    let realm = try! Realm()

func checkForExistingPin() -> Bool {

    let existingCode = realm.objects(pinCode.self)
    if existingCode.count == 0  {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}

func enterNewPin(newPin:String) {
    if checkForExistingPin()    {
        let oldCode = realm.objects(pinCode.self).first
        try! realm.write {
            oldCode!.pin = newPin
        }
    }
    let newPinObject = pinCode()
    newPinObject.pin = newPin
    realm.add(newPinObject)
}

func checkPin(pin:String) -> Bool   {
    if checkForExistingPin()    {
        if pin == realm.objects(pinCode.self).first?.pin    {
            return true
        }
        else    {
            return false
        }
    }
    return false
}   
}
```

Here is the ViewController part

```
import UIKit

class InitialViewController: UIViewController {
var currentPinCode = ""
var pinEntered = ""
var firstPinEntered = ""
var secondPinEntered = ""
let myPin = pinCode()

@IBOutlet weak var enterPinCodeField: UITextField!

@IBAction func GoButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let enteredPin = enterPinCodeField?.text
    if self.myPin.checkPin(pin: enteredPin)    {
        print ("Correct Pin")
    }
    else    {
        print ("Incorrect Pin")
    }
}

@IBAction func NewUserButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("New user selected!")

    let pinCodeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter New PIN", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    pinCodeAlert.addTextField (configurationHandler:{textField1 in

        textField1.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField1.placeholder = "Enter new PIN"
        textField1.isSecureTextEntry = true
    })

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)   {(action) in
        let firstPinEntry = pinCodeAlert.textFields?.first
        print ("First PIN entered: " , firstPinEntry!.text)
        self.confirmPin(firstPin: firstPinEntry!.text!)
    }

    pinCodeAlert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(pinCodeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func confirmPin(firstPin: String)   {
    let pinCodeAlert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Re-enter New PIN", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    pinCodeAlert2.addTextField (configurationHandler:{textField1 in

        textField1.keyboardType = .numberPad
        textField1.placeholder = "Re-enter new PIN"
        textField1.isSecureTextEntry = true


    })
    let okAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)   {(action) in
        let secondPinEntered = pinCodeAlert2.textFields?.first
        print ("2nd PIN entered: " , secondPinEntered?.text! as Any)

        if firstPin != secondPinEntered?.text!   {
            print("PINs dont match!")
            let pinCodesDontMatch = UIAlertController(title: "PINs don't match!", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)


            let okAction3 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)  {(action) in
            }
            pinCodesDontMatch.addAction(okAction3)
            self.present(pinCodesDontMatch, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else    {
            let newPinSet = UIAlertController(title: "New PIN Set", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)   {(action) in
            }
            newPinSet.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(newPinSet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.myPin.pin = String((secondPinEntered?.text)!)
        }
    }


    pinCodeAlert2.addAction(okAction2)
    self.present(pinCodeAlert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var PinCodeField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The line I am having problems with is:

```
 if self.myPin.checkPin(pin: enteredPin)
```

I have tried a few variations on it without any success.

The error I get is "Value of type 'pinCode' has no member 'checkPin'"
So I get the impression that it is looking for a member rather than a function called checkPin.

How do I tell it that I'm trying to point it to a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkPin` function has been declared for the `pinCodeManager` class, but you are trying to call the function for a `pinCode` object. You need to create a `pinCodeManager` instance to call `checkPin`.

Comment: Thank you. 
I'm now running into a problem in checkForExistingPin() which has the line
let existingCode = realm.objects(pinCode.self)
which produces an object, but I'm trying to get the pin associated with that object.

Comment: You should mark this as answered and ask a new question. I'll answer here this time though: `realm.objects()` will give you ALL pinCode instances. If you're sure you only have one in the realm, you can use `.first?` to give you an optional result, and dereference that with `.pin`. i.e. `realm.objects(pinCode.self).first?.pin`